# how to sql query for patients between dates

Tags: sql

I'd like query for patients having received their first diagnosis of x between 2019 - present and excluding those patients that received a diagnosis of x prior to 2019.

When I use the query below, I result in the same number of patient with or without statement: `AND d.[DOS] !< '2019'`

Can someone help?

Thanks!

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[DiagnosisCD]
      ,[DOS]
FROM [diags] d
WHERE [DiagnosisCD] IN ('H91.2', 'H91.20', 'H91.21', 'H91.22', 'H91.23')
   AND d.[DOS] >= '2019'
   AND d.[DOS] !< '2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT [id]
FROM [diags] d
WHERE [DiagnosisCD] IN ('H91.2', 'H91.20', 'H91.21', 'H91.22', 'H91.23')
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(DOS) >= 2019
```

If `DOS` is really a date then use:

```
HAVING MIN(DOS) >= '2019-01-01'
```

If you want all rows related to these diagnoses -- even if there is more than one per patient -- then you can use `exists`:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM [diags] d
WHERE d.DiagnosisCD IN ('H91.2', 'H91.20', 'H91.21', 'H91.22', 'H91.23') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM diags d2
                  WHERE d2.id = d.id AND
                        d2.DiagnosisCD IN ('H91.2', 'H91.20', 'H91.21', 'H91.22', 'H91.23') AND
                        d2.dos < 2019
                 );
```